# Waterloo Programming Contest: The Game of 31

Tags: java, programming-challenge

Please review my program for the [Game of 31](http://acm.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~acm00/110619/A.pdf).

> The game of 31 was a favourite of con artists who rode the railroads in days of yore. The game
>   is played with a deck of 24 cards: four labelled each of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. The cards in the deck are
>   visible to both players, who alternately withdraw one card from the deck and place it on a pile.
>   The object of the game is to be the last player to lay a card such that the sum of the cards in
>   the pile does not exceed 31. Your task is to determine the eventual winner of a partially played
>   game, assuming each player plays the remainder of the game using a perfect strategy.
>
> For example, in the following game player B wins:
>
> Player A plays 3
>
> Player B plays 5
>
> Player A plays 6
>
> Player B plays 6
>
> Player A plays 5
>
> Player B plays 6
>
> **Input:** The input will consist of several lines; each line consists of a sequence of zero or more digits
>   representing a partially completed game. The first digit is player A’s move; the second player
>   B’s move; and so on. You are to complete the game using a perfect strategy for both players and to determine who wins.
>
> **Output:** For each game, print a line consisting of the input, followed by a space, followed by A or B to
>   indicate the eventual winner of the game.

**GameOf31.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class GameOf31 {

private static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
static Map<Integer, Integer> cardsKnt = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
private static final int MAXSUM = 31;

//initialises the hash map with keys 1 to 6 and makes the values for each equal to 4
//this is because the deck of 24 cards has 4 of each cards numbered 1 to 6
public GameOf31(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
        cardsKnt.put(i, 4);
}

//Since I accept input as an integer, I separate it into an integer array
public static int[] separateSequence(int sequence){
    int[] numseq = new int[10];
    Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<Integer>();

    while(sequence > 0){
        s1.push(sequence % 10);
        sequence /= 10;
    }

    int sz = s1.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i){
        numseq[i] = s1.pop();
    }

    return numseq;
}

//Pretty straight forward, calculates final winner
public static char getWinner(int[] sequence){
    char winner = 'X';
    int tempSum = 0;
    boolean aTurn = true, bTurn = false, tempTurn = false;

    /*
     * This loop removes cards already played in the turn from the hash map,
     * then determines who's turn is next.
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length; ++i){
        tempSum += sequence[i];
        if(cardsKnt.containsKey(sequence[i])){
            int knt = cardsKnt.get(sequence[i]);
            --knt;
            cardsKnt.put(sequence[i], knt);
            tempTurn = aTurn;
            aTurn = bTurn;
            bTurn = tempTurn;
        }
    }

    boolean loop = true;
    while(loop){

        if(tempSum == MAXSUM){

            winner = bTurn == true ? 'A' : 'B';
            loop = false;

        } else if (tempSum > 31){

            winner = aTurn == true ? 'B' : 'A';
            loop = false;

        } else {

            if(aTurn){

                int sum = 0, maxsum = 0, nextToPick = 0;

                for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i){

                    //If the card with number 'i' hasn't been used 4 times
                    if(cardsKnt.get(i) > 0){
                        sum = tempSum + i;

                        //If sum is equal to 31 or less, we can still do another iteration
                        if(sum <= 31){
                            if(sum > maxsum){
                                maxsum = sum;
                                nextToPick = i;
                            }
                        } 
                        //else we know the winner is the previous player.
                        else {
                            winner = 'B';
                            return winner;
                        }
                    } 
                    sum = 0;
                }

                tempSum = maxsum;
                int knt = cardsKnt.get(nextToPick);
                --knt;
                //perhaps there is a better way to change hash map values directly?
                cardsKnt.put(nextToPick, knt);
                tempTurn = aTurn;
                aTurn = bTurn;
                bTurn = tempTurn;

            } else if(bTurn) {

                int sum = 0, maxsum = 0, nextToPick = 0;

                for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i){
                    if(cardsKnt.get(i) > 0){
                        sum = tempSum + i;
                        if(sum <= MAXSUM){
                            if(sum > maxsum){
                                maxsum = sum;
                                nextToPick = i;
                            }
                        } else {
                            winner = 'A';
                            return winner;
                        }
                    } 
                    sum = 0;
                }

                tempSum = maxsum;
                int knt = cardsKnt.get(nextToPick);
                --knt;
                cardsKnt.put(nextToPick, knt);
                tempTurn = aTurn;
                aTurn = bTurn;
                bTurn = tempTurn;

            }
        }
    }

    return winner;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    new GameOf31();
    int input = stdin.nextInt();

    char Winner = getWinner(separateSequence(input));
    System.out.println(input + "\t" + (Winner == 'X' ? "Error; no winner." : Winner));


}

}
```

Thanks in advance, any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Int too small to represent input

Currently, if there is a very long input such as `111122223333`, the numeric value of that input will not fit within an `int`.  I would suggest leaving the input in `String` format, which would simplify your `separateSequence()` function because you wouldn't need to use a stack to reverse the digits.

## Array instead of HashMap

I noticed that you had this comment for removing a card from the deck:

> ```
>             int knt = cardsKnt.get(nextToPick);
>             --knt;
>             //perhaps there is a better way to change hash map values directly?
>             cardsKnt.put(nextToPick, knt);
> ```

It looks like you found the `HashMap` a little awkward to use for this purpose.  You can use an array to represent your card deck and it would simplify your code:

```
              // Initializing the array:
              int[] cards = new int[7];

              for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
                  cards[i] = 4;
              }

              // Checking if a card remains in the deck:
              if (cards[sequence[i]] > 0) {
              }

              // Removing a card from the deck:
              cards[nextToPick]--;
```

## Solving logic incorrect

I tried the following cases:

```
356656   B
356655   B
356654   B
```

The first test case adds up to 31 already, so B should win because B was last to play.  However, in the other 2 test cases, the sum adds up to 30 and 29 respectively.  So player A should win because player A plays next and can play a card to make the sum 31.  So something is wrong with your game solving logic.

From a casual inspection of your solving loop, it looks like you are using some kind of greedy heuristic to play the lower numbered cards first.  I believe that in order to play perfect strategy, you will need to do something like an Alpha Beta search instead.

Answer (score 0):

`s1, sz` - are too short names

there are to many if's inside one of another: `if{if{if}}}`

`getWinner` is too long, it would be nice to break it into several methods.